# Using a single method struct vs function closures

Tags: performance, go, struct, closures

In my application I have tasks that I want to perform in parallel. Many tasks have components are not thread safe. For example, if I want to have multiple threads all calling `io.CopyBuffer`, they will each need their own `[]byte` buffer instance.

To avoid plumbing a lot of of state in my workers, I ended up creating many tiny structs to bundle state along side a function. The structs are instantiated once at the start of each worker and are connected together with other similar objects.

E.g. for the `io.CopyBuffer` example:

```
type Copier struct {
    buffer []byte
}

func NewCopier(buffer []byte) *Copier {
    return &Copier{buffer}
}

func (c *Copier) Copy(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) (int64, error) {
    return io.CopyBuffer(w, r, c.buffer)
}
```

To make writing methods like this a bit easier, I started using a pattern where I return a function closure to tie the state to the function instead of using a struct:

```
type Copier = func(io.Writer, io.Reader) (int64, error)

func NewCopier(buffer []byte) Copier {
    return func(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) (int64, error) {
        return io.CopyBuffer(w, r, buffer)
    }
}
```

I've been really liking working with this closure approach. It ends up feeling a bit cleaner when I go to tie multiple functions like this together, and I also like that for each component that all of the logic stays wrapped up nicely in one place.

Some questions I wanted feedback on:

- Does the closure approach have any notable flaws?
- Are there major performance differences between the two approaches?
- Do I need to be worried about garbage collection here?

I'm pretty new to Golang, so all feedback is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: No. No (but benchmark to be sure). No. (The name of the language is plain "Go").

Comment: @Volker I'm over thinking this I'm guessing? Also am now seeing [this faq](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang)... going to take some time to beat calling it "golang" out of my brain :)

Comment: Overall I'm pretty impressed with the type system in this language. Syntax seems to stay fairly simple/sane, and type aliasing makes writing code in a more functional style with high-order functions feel very smooth.